# How to export only selected row in csv in backpack laravel

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have using `pro` version of backpack for laravel.
I have used `enableExportButtons` in list operation to export data.
I have also used `enableBulkActions` to enable checkbox in each rows.

Now, I want to export only selected rows. How can I do this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Backpack doesn't have a built-in way to do that, it just uses the Export functionality from DataTables. The only way I see possible right now is to [create a custom operation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-operations#creating-a-custom-operation-1) that downloads a PDF with the Show view.

We do have a closed-source operation that does just that, we call it "Download". If you're interested please contact the Backpack team.